# Return latest balance between two dates

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a formula that could give me the latest balance between two dates. I have one cell for the starting date and cell one for the end date.I also have some duplicate dates for each accounts in my file. This is the formula that I have right now in my file that is working well but now I need to put the date range in the formula:
=LOOKUP(10^35;$F$15:$F$68/($D$15:$D$68=$E8))

To translate the formula that I have in the file vs the example below, it would be something like this:

```
=LOOKUP(10^35;$C$2:$C$4/($D$2:$D$5=$F4))
```

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DATE | AMOUNT | BALANCE | ACCOUNT | START DATE: | Jan-1-2020 |
| 2 | Jan-5-2020 | 50$ | 50$ | ABC... | END DATE: | Dec-31-2020 |
| 3 | Dec-30-2020 | 60$ | 110$ | ABC... |  |  |
| 4 | Dec-30-2020 | 40$ | 150$ | ABC... |  | ABC... |
| 5 | Dec-31-2020 | 100$ | 100$ | DEF... |  | DEF... |

The expected result for account ABC... would be 150$

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($C$2:$C$5)/(($A$2:$A$5>=$F$1)*($A$2:$A$5<=$F$2)*($D$2:$D$5=F4)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott! Unfortunately, for now, it gives me REF errors on 2 accounts and the last account doesn't return the right value. Could you tell me what the "1" mean at the end of your formula? It's maybe on my side that I have to adjust something. In this case, we don'T need to put the double quotation mark in this part ">="; "<="???

Comment: Thanks Scott! I've just found my mistake. Instead of entering "C:C" in the beginning of the formula, I've selected the cell range C2:C5 But why exactly does it give a REF error when I select all the cells that has values on Column C??? P.S. It solves one issue but created another :P. This formula works for the period of January-1-2020 to December-1-2020 but as soon as I will start a new period (January-1-2021 to December-31-2021). I lose the latest balance for each accounts :S. Is there a way to tell Excel to report the latest balance of each accounts (the last writen data of the account??

Comment: You need the whole column due to the fact that the aggregate returns the row number and not the relative location.  As to the second question that would be a new question with its own post.

Comment: I understand the words that you wriite lol :P but I still don't get the difference between a selected cell range or relative location vs selecting the whole column? Excel has a language of his own as I work more and more in it ;). Thanks for trying to explain how the agregate works ;). For my second question, it's okay. I did some adjustments. Thanks again for the help!